# Where image sizes 1536x1536 and 2048x2048 are registered?

Tags: wordpress

WordPress 5.9.1

I have deactivated all the plugins and showed all image sizes via wp_get_registered_image_subsizes().

[image]

I can see 1536x1536 and 2048x2048. I can't find where these image sizes were registered. Neither in WordPress itself, nor in the theme. Could you comment on it? Where are they registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worpdress registered them in [wp-includes/media.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/401e5d71756179162f5a25a1f947e416760ce7df/wp-includes/media.php#L5125)
You can remove them:

```php
remove_image_size('1536x1536');
remove_image_size('2048x2048');
```